# The Class data is never used

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm trying to create a data base but it said the class data is never used, also the "message" at Message.message(context, ""+e) said cannot resolve method 'message(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)

can anybody help me how to solve the problem? below are my codings

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Message;


public class data extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "datadatabase";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "datatable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Bmi";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT , Bmi VARCHAR(255);";

    public data(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }
    }
```

and for Message.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Message {
    public static void message (Context context, String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> it said the class data is never used

because you never used the `data` class anywhere.

> also the "message" at Message.message(context, ""+e) said cannot
>   resolve method 'message(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)

because You're imported `android.os.Message` instead of your custom `Message` class.

So change `import android.os.Message;` to `your.package.Message`.

Comment: already tried but it still gives error

Comment: i already solved the problems, thank you